# Why can't I access getParentFragmentManager() from androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have been looking at the androidx.fragment.app.Fragment documentation and there is this method `getParentFragmentManager()`. However, in my Android project it doesn't recognize it. I am using kotlin and it says: Unresolved reference: getParentFragmentManager. Why does it happen?

Comment: what version of androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your fragment ktx version to 1.2.5 and use `parentFragmentManager` like property